# Problems with creating primary keys in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, primary-key

I have table that has null type of data and it need to be null

replacement parts 0,m-> Repair

So replacement parts can be part of repair but every repair don't need to have replacement parts and when I am creating tables I putted for replacement parts id null, but problem is when I am creating primary key it can be only with not null. What to do?

Comment: use a unique key instead. thats allows to have **NULL**

Comment: So Like this; Replacement parts (Id unique, date date, description nvarchar(255))???

Comment: You proabably need a many to many relationship between repairs and parts.

Comment: it need to be 0,m . School project and they said need that

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are different products. Wrong tags might lead to answers that don't work for you.

Comment: Typically you might have a table of parts, a table of repairs, and a table identifying which part goes with which repair, so, what's the problem with that idea?

Answer (score 0):

The question describes only one half of the relation between repairs and replacement parts. 
You stated that a repair may consist of zero ore more replacement parts.

But (1) can the same replacement part be taken in zero or more repairs, or (2) is a replacement part consumed by a repair such that it can occur only zero or one time in a repair?

It is necessary to make this clear, because (1) and (2) lead to different database schemes:

(1) is a many - to - many relationship and leads to a separate table connecting parts and repairs:

```sql
create table part (
    partId int primary key
);

create table repair (
    repairId int primary key
    );

create table part_repair (
    partId int references part (partId),
    repairId int references repair (repairId)
    primary key (partId, repairId)
    );
```

(2) part may be used in zero or one repair; store repair-id in part:

```sql
create table repair (
    repairId int primary key
    );

create table part (
    partId int primary key,
    repairId int references repair(repairId)
);
```

Note that `repairId` in part may take on `NULL` values for those parts that are not assigned to a repair.

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Hm - @Strawberry: Why do you think so?

Comment: Because I mis-read. The first part is fine. The second idea is decidely unlikely, but I think you said as much